# SQL посчитать количество заказов

Tags: sql, запрос

Помогите написать запрос, который из верхней таблицы выведет нижнюю
вроде так работает но неполностью

> SELECT count(Объект) from Таблица1 where Заказчик='МТЗ'

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А "не полностью" - это как ? Вроде должно выбрать именно то что нарисовано именно так как написано

Comment: надо выбрать только МТЗ

Comment: ну вы именно это и делаете

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT заказчик, count(*) кол_во from Таблица1 group by заказчик having count(*) > 1
```